# Sort DB data and display in list view

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursor

I get data from my DB using

```
cursor = db.query("WebLeadMaster", select, "condition1="+conditionVal1+
" and condition2="+ConditionVal2,null, null, null, "RegistrationTime DESC");
```

I am getting the data in my cursor alright. To display the data, i use the following code:

```
    SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
            R.layout.resultleadlookup, cursor, columns, to); 
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    lstResult.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

So, I cannot modify the contents of the cursor. The sort query has condition "RegistrationTime" which is a ***String data type.*** As you can see in the image below, it is not in a proper sorted format. (not according to date-time).

What changes should i make in my code so that it would sort properly according to date-time?

[image: expected output and actual output]

If i alter my DB query, to look like

```
cursor = db.query("WebLeadMaster", select, "condition1="+conditionVal1+
" and condition2="+ConditionVal2,null, null, null, null);
```

it gives an ascending order. All i want it the descending order.

Comment: just reverse it will become descending

Comment: Your time is given in _descending_ order, that means the highest values are at the top.  You want the default _ascending_ order, see my answer for code examples.

Comment: @Sam hehe i didn't notice that for the first time i've read this question but, you're right, RegistrationTime is sorted in descending order ... and he is trying to sort data in desc. order by id??(second field in rows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, i changed my table structure. I added another field "_id" to it. Set the property as  **AUTO INCREMENT** to it, and sorted the list with respect to **_id** field.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest suggestion would be to save the date in a different format (but still saved as string) into the database. If you would save the data into SQLite’s default date format (YYYY-MM-DD HH:NN:SS), you can easily sort the dates.

To display the date in your format, you would only just need to reformat the date into the correct format.

Comment: android gave error for that format. So i changed it to (yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss). But still I am getting the same problem...
Also, the RegistrationDate is of data type "String" so, don't know if the change in format would make any difference or not.

Comment: dennisg meant that you should change data in db to this format(stil string/varchar but stored in "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" / since SQLIte has no datetime format) ... then you can sort this column as string and will be fine ...

Comment: I did use that Selvin... but if i have time value: (2012-04-15 10:30:20 AM), (2012-04-15 11:10:20 PM),  (2012-04-15 12:30:20 PM) and (2012-04-15 2:30:20 PM), It shows the DESC order to be:  (2012-04-15 12:30:20 PM), (2012-04-15 11:10:20 PM),(2012-04-15 10:30:20 AM), (2012-04-15 2:30:20 PM) which is not correct!

Comment: @Pallavi change the time values to:
(2012-04-15 10:30:20), (2012-04-15 23:10:20), (2012-04-15 12:30:20) and (2012-04-15 14:30:20)
i.e. remove PM and AM, use a 24 hour format.

Answer (score 1):

If you r using ORM you can sort the data by timestamp.
ORM makes data insertion and data retrieval easier from database.
You have to include jar files to your project to use ORM...

Comment: the date-Time is of data type "String" sir.

Answer (score 0):

since SQLite has no datetime type, store date type as LONG/INT/NUMERIC in SQLite (EPOCH time) it will be easier to sort

then add `ViewBinder` to `Adapter`

```
        /*field in activity/fragment*/
        final static SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); //or other format that you wana to show in ListView
        ...
        mAdapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {

            @Override
            public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor,
                    int columnIndex) {
                final int id = view.getId();
                switch (id) {
                    case R.id.id_of_textview_with_date_data:
                        final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                        cal.setTimeInMillis(cursor.getLong(columnIndex));
                        ((TextView) view).setText(sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

... or as dennisg pointed store it as STRING/VARCHAR **edit**: in "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" format

Comment: SQLite has the DATETIME, DATE, and TIMESTAMP data types. SQLite converts them to INTEGER, REAL or TEXT for you with the built in [built-in date and time functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

Comment: @Sam lol, lol and lol again from documentation ... `SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates and/or times.` ... anyway show me working code for updating/inserting datetype using `db.update(cv)` with mixed long or string values ...

Comment: You are right that it is not a base _storage class_, but this statement is not an error `CREATE TABLE foo (time TIMESTAMP);` since the data type TIMESTAMP exists.

Comment: but you can still put there string in one row and int to second row (to the same column)... so you have to control it from your app

Comment: Yeah, it would be nice if SQLite held strict type definitions not _type affinity_. Though I leave the app out of the time keeping and let SQLite maintain it. Example: `CREATE TABLE foo (created TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, modified TIMESTAMP NOT NULL);` and `INSERT INTO foo (modified) VALUES (CURRENT_TIME);` This way I can't screw up my own data.

Comment: true, true ... especially when default format depends on device Locale and you can't assume how exatcly data looks in db if you're using default formatter and store it as a string