# database performance crushed by SimpleDateFormat.parse

Tags: android, sql, database

I have a database where about 100 rows have a Date associated with them.  To store them in the SQL database, I convert them to a string and store them.  Then, when reading these rows back I use SimpleDateFormat.parse().  This apparently eats about 80-90% of my time when reading rows back out of my database.

Does anyone know a better way to store/read Dates in Android and its databases?

Comment: surely Android SQL has a native date/time format?

Comment: you can store daya as long see my answer here   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10139141/sort-db-data-and-display-in-list-view/10140140#10140140     cal.setTimeInMillis(cursor.getLong(columnIndex));